# Netty HttpServer Chrome Browser Multiple Requests

Tags: google-chrome, netty

We use Netty, version 4.1.13. We create HttpServer, HttpServerInitializer, HttpServerHandler and start it through using a port.When we make a request from Chrome Browser, HttpServerInitializer is called 3 or 4 times (sometimes 3, sometimes 4) and it is called again after 10 seconds.When we make a request through Microsoft Edge or through console, it is called one times as expected and HttpServerHandler handles the rest.

What should we do to prevent HttpServerInitializer's handling unnecessary extra requests.We have session operations attached to pipeline on Initializer, so this is a critical issue for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour of browsers for HTTP 1 is to open several connections (how many depends on the browser) to do requests in parallel. Like that, they can retrieve resources like css, js, images,... in parallel.

The number of connection is configurable into the browser. In general there are two preferences: the maximum number of connections by hostname and the total maximum number of opened connections.

See also: http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=0

So, when you start a request with Chrome, it opens several connections, even if it use only one if there is not so much request done. The idle an unused connections will be closed after some seconds.

I think that's why you see the HttpServerInitializer being called several times, only because there are several connections. So, server side, it's normal, because you don't know if it's different clients or only one with many connections.

I advice you to not do costly operation on Connection Opened event, but only when you receive a valid message/request. Your initializer should only configure the necessary handlers on the pipeline which should be quick and simple, and nothing else.